# set multiple animation on single element, when trigger them one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I want to set multiple animation on single element on the phone, when trigger them one by one. I achieve this by the under method , but have 2 problems:

1. I need accurate position and size, so I use `top bottom width height`. But I know use these properties, the browser need to render again, so it is not efficient.
2. On the second animation, although I set `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, but still need to set `0%` keyframes to assure second animation start point is on the first animation end point.

Thanks for more efficient method.

[my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/colorWin/0bac15cx/13/)

html:

```
<button id="first">first</button>
<button id="second">second</button>
<div class="moon"></div>
```

css:

```
.first {
  animation-name: first;
}

.second {
  animation-name: second;
}

@-webkit-keyframes first {
  100% {
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    left: 4.1rem;
    bottom: 11.7rem;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes second {
  0% {
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    left: 4.1rem;
    bottom: 11.7rem;
  }
  100% {
    height: 4rem;
    width: 4rem;
    left: 5.8rem;
    bottom: 10.5rem;
  }
}
```

js:

```
var $moon = $('.moon');
$('#first').click(function() {
  $moon.addClass('animated first');
});
$('#second').click(function() {
  $moon.addClass('animated second');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try with the JQuery keyframe plugin, you can download it here:

https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes

You can then initialize a set of variables such as height width top and left like this:

```
var $moon = $('.moon'),
    newHeight = '0',
    newWidth = '0',
    newTop = '0',
    newLeft = '0';
```

And then for the clicks you could try dynamic variables for each click incrementing 40 each time it clicks?

```
$('#first').click(function() {
    newHeight = $moon.height() + 40+'px';
    newWidth = $moon.width() + 40+'px';
    newTop = $moon.position().top + 80+'px';
    newLeft = $moon.position().left + 80+'px';

    $moon.removeClass('first');
    $moon.removeClass('second');

    $.keyframe.define([{
        name: 'first',    
        '0%': {'height': $moon.height()+'px',
             'width': $moon.width() +'px',
             'left': $moon.position().left+'px',
             'top': $moon.position().top+'px'
                },
        '100%': {'height': newHeight,
                 'width': newWidth,
                 'left': newLeft,
                 'top': newTop
                }
    }]);
  $moon.addClass('first');
});

$('#second').click(function() {          
    newHeight = $moon.height() + 40+'px';
    newWidth = $moon.width() + 40+'px';
    newTop = $moon.position().top + 80+'px';
    newLeft = $moon.position().left + 80+'px';

    $moon.removeClass('first');  
    $moon.removeClass('second');  

    $.keyframe.define([{
        name: 'second',  
        '0%': {'height': $moon.height()+'px',
             'width': $moon.width()+'px',
             'left': $moon.position().left+'px',
             'top': $moon.position().top+'px',
                },  
        '100%': {'height': newHeight,
                 'width': newWidth,
                 'left': newLeft,
                 'top': newTop,
                }
    }]);
    $moon.addClass('second');
});
```

Thought you might give that a try, Leo.